# How to Session variable pass one controller to another controller using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

```
I have Two Controller.

1.Login Controller
2. NewsLine Controller
```

Login Controller Below Code:

```
$query = $this->login_model->select_login($_POST);
            if ($query) {
                $user = array(
                    'uname' => $query['uname'],
                    'pwd' => $query['pwd']
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata($user);
                $_SESSION['id'] = $user['id'];
                redirect('Newsline');
            }
```

My Question is How To $_SESSION['id] pass to Newsline Controller

Comment: in CI set session $this->session->set_userdata('id',$user['id']);  and get session $this->session->userdata('id');

Comment: id display null value

Comment: you can't set id in $user array.. so how can get it.

Comment: first set $this->session->set_userdata('id',$query['id']);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [CodeIgniter documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html) to set the session data you an do following,

```
$newdata = array(
         'username'  => 'uname',
         'email'     => 'uname@some-site.com'
);

$this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
```

Now this is how you an retrive the data,

```
$session_id = $this->session->userdata('email');
```

In your case your code should look like this,

```
if ($query) {
   $user = array(
         'uname' => $query['uname'],
         'pwd' => $query['pwd'],
         'id' => $query['id']
   );
   $this->session->set_userdata($user);
   redirect('Newsline');
}
```

To retrive ID on NewsLine controller,

```
$session_id = $this->session->userdata('id');
```